# Centering divs inside container when inline-block on container is not working

Tags: html, css, containers

I used the search feature and found plenty of people suggesting putting the `.container` with a `display:inline-block` and then giving the `.box` a `margin:0 auto;` 
Something like this:

```
.container {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
margin:5rem auto;
padding:0;
}

.box {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:20%;
height:auto;
vertical-align:top;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Here is a fiddle where it will center and send each `div` below the next one
http://jsfiddle.net/ayezee33/3hk12c8g/

Here is a fiddle of me adding `inline-block` to the `.box` class. How can I center it looking like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/ayezee33/7qdhjtrp/

Essentially I am trying to center these 3 divs called `.box` in the middle of 100% of the screen width. I want the text to still be aligned left, but the box itself to be centered. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close with your first example.

By applying the style `inline-block` you're essentially now dealing with something that interacts kind of like a text element. As such the way to center the `div`s is to apply `text-align:center` to the parent `div`. (in this case `.container`). Then override this style on the child `div`s.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7qdhjtrp/1/)**

PS. Added blue background color just so visual confirmation of centering.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. It worked great. I would never had thought this would affect the position of the block element. Not sure I fully understand but now I can do some more research. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @AyeZee33, it's because you're no longer refering to a `block` element, but an `inline-block` element :) PS, if you found this to be the correct answer for you, please mark it, so that people searching can find it :)

Comment: I believe I just did with the green checkmark is that correct?